# how to render bootstrap glyphicons in sphinx documentation?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, python-sphinx, glyphicons

I am using sphinx documentation tool to document my website. I want to list how to reproduce something by clicking on specific icons. Can I add bootstrap glyphicons/fontawesome in sphinx?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to insert FontAwesome etc. icons is to use raw HTML directive.

```
.. raw:: html

   <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
```

If you need something along the liness "this is how you click buttons" another solution is to record GIF animation from your screen e.g. using [LiceCAP](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/).

Comment: How can I include the fontawesome  library?

Comment: Customize your Sphinx theme files to have `<head>` section which includes FontAwesome from their CDN according to FontAwesome instructions.